# How to set different orientation for different screens in corona

Tags: lua, orientation, coronasdk

I have different screens in my corona application, and I want to show one screen i.e splash screen in landscape mode, and the other menu in portrait mode. How can I achieve this in corona?

Here is my code that I am using in build file:

```
settings =
{
    orientation =
    {
        default = "landscapeRight",
        supported = { "landscapeLeft", "landscapeRight" },
    },
}
```

Comment: @ dk3611:As my research, I found that corona doesn't support it right now. So, you have to individually code for those scenes(either in portrait/landscape). For more info, visit this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411137/how-to-set-individual-device-orientation-for-individual-pages-corona-sdk@